# QT multilanguage app

Tags: qt, qt4

I am new in Qt framework and now, I want to create an app which supports multi-language display. I known there is a way to do: Qt Linguist. I searched, and archieved some information about lupdate, lrelease ... 
 But I just have Qt Creator IDE, how can I run or compile lupdate, lrelease ??? 
How can  I create *.ts file ?

Please give me some code example or guide to do. (I often use Qt Designer to create GUI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no option in QtCreator to use QtLinguist - you have to do it manually. [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/linguist-manager.html) you have an excellent documentation about how to do it. I have learned from there also.